# How to prevent a dlopened library from using certain libc functions?

Tags: c, unix, linker

I'm writing a Linux/Unix program that has a lot of implementation in plugins that are dlopened by the program on-demand.

I'd like to prevent these plugin libraries from using some libc functions that mess with global state of the host process (such as manipulating signal handlers and suchlike).

What would be the best way to do this?

As far as I know I can't employ the classical `LD_PRELOAD` trick here since the libs are dlopened.

Comment: [Running plugins in a sandbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786775/running-plugins-in-a-sandbox)?

Comment: @BoPersson Well, I can't do that, the plugins actually implement much of the useful functionality of the app, I should've been more specific about that...

Comment: If library code normally makes a call you want to.prevent, what do you want to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

In practical terms, you can't. Code running from a library runs with the full privileges of the host application. Don't load libraries that you don't trust to not do stupid things.

You could conceivably examine the library before loading it and (for instance) reject libraries which have unexpected dependencies, or which have relocations for functions which they shouldn't be using. (This could be accomplished using `ldd` or `readelf`, for instance.) However, this will never be entirely reliable; there are numerous ways that a malicious library could hide its use of various functions.

Comment: I'm not trying to protect against a malicious library (not only is it impossible in this case, but also not a design intention), it's basically just supposed to be a hint, something like _"Your plugin called function such and such, please don't do that, check the documentation on how to accomplish that properly"_.